# Google Calendar API, incremental sync: does each calendar require its own sync token?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

If I have several Google Calendars under my Google account and want to [incrementally sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#incremental_sync) all of the calendars, should I keep one common sync token for all calendars or a separate sync token for each calendar? In other words, are `Events.getNextSyncToken()` and `Events.List.setSyncToken()` specific to a single calendar or to all events no matter what calendar they belong to?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the sample Code based on the Document you have provided:

```
// Construct the {@link Calendar.Events.List} request, but don't execute it yet.
Calendar.Events.List request = client.events().list("primary");
```

It looks like each calendar have their own sync token.